# Bug in JSON mapper class

Tags: java, json, hadoop, mapreduce

Im working on a MapReduce (Map only task) which reads the JSON file and extracts the elements from JSON input. Input data:

```
{"type":"cloud_monitor","format":"default","version":"1.0","id":"71101cb85441995d11a43bb","start":"1413585245.921","cp":"254623","message":{"proto":"http","protoVer":"1.1","status":"403","cliIP":"23.79.231.14","reqPort":"80","reqHost":"ksd.metareactor.com","reqMethod":"GET","reqPath":"%2findex.php","reqQuery":"path%3d57%26product_id%3d49%26route%3d%255Cwinnt%255Cwin.ini%2500.","respCT":"text/html","respLen":"286","bytes":"286","UA":"mozilla-saturn","fwdHost":"origin-demo2-akamaized.scoe-sil.net"},"reqHdr":{"accEnc":"gzip,%20deflate","cookie":"PHPSESSID%3dkkqoodvfe0rt9l7lbvqghk6e15%3bcurrency%3dUSD%3blanguage%3den"}}
```

I've declared String variables for the JSON Arrays: Message & reqHdr and you can see them in the context.write() method

Map Class:

```
public class JsonMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text> {

public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    String type;
    String format;
    String version;
    String id;
    String start;
    String cp;
    // variables for message and reqHdr
    String[] line = value.toString().split("\\n");
    if (line.length > 0) {
        for(int i=0; i<line.length; i++) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonobj      = new JSONObject(line[i]);
                    type    = (String) jsonobj.get("type");
                    format  = (String) jsonobj.get("format");
                    version = (String) jsonobj.get("version");
                    id      = (String) jsonobj.get("id");
                    start   = (String) jsonobj.get("start"); 
                    cp      = (String) jsonobj.get("cp");

                // Message Variable array
                JSONArray messageArray  = (JSONArray) jsonobj.get("message");
                for(int j=0; j<messageArray.length(); j++) {
                    JSONObject jsonmessageobject = messageArray.getJSONObject(j);
                    proto       = jsonmessageobject.getString("proto");
                    protoVer    = jsonmessageobject.getString("protoVer");
                    cliIP       = jsonmessageobject.getString("cliIP");
                    reqPort     = jsonmessageobject.getString("reqPort");
                    reqHost     = jsonmessageobject.getString("reqHost");
                    reqMethod   = jsonmessageobject.getString("reqMethod");
                    reqPath     = jsonmessageobject.getString("reqPath");
                    reqQuery    = jsonmessageobject.getString("reqQuery");
                    reqCT       = jsonmessageobject.getString("reqCT");
                    reqLen      = jsonmessageobject.getString("reqLen");
                    sslVer      = jsonmessageobject.getString("sslVer");
                    status      = jsonmessageobject.getString("status");
                    redirURL    = jsonmessageobject.getString("redirURL");
                    respCT      = jsonmessageobject.getString("respCT");
                    respLen     = jsonmessageobject.getString("respLen");
                    bytes       = jsonmessageobject.getString("bytes");
                    UA          = jsonmessageobject.getString("UA");
                    fwdHost     = jsonmessageobject.getString("fwdHost");
                }

                // reqHdr variable array
                JSONArray reqHdrArray   = (JSONArray) jsonobj.get("reqHdr");
                for(int k=0; k<reqHdrArray.length(); k++) {
                    JSONObject jsonreqHdrobject = reqHdrArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    accEnc      = jsonreqHdrobject.getString("accEnc");
                    accLang     = jsonreqHdrobject.getString("accLang");
                    auth        = jsonreqHdrobject.getString("auth");
                    reqHdr_cacheCtl = jsonreqHdrobject.getString("cacheCtl");
                    reqHdr_conn = jsonreqHdrobject.getString("conn");
                    reqHdr_contMD5 = jsonreqHdrobject.getString("contMD5");
                    cookie      = jsonreqHdrobject.getString("cookie");
                    DNT         = jsonreqHdrobject.getString("DNT");
                    expect      = jsonreqHdrobject.getString("expect");
                    ifMatch     = jsonreqHdrobject.getString("ifMatch");
                    ifMod       = jsonreqHdrobject.getString("ifMod");
                    ifNone      = jsonreqHdrobject.getString("ifNone");
                    ifRange     = jsonreqHdrobject.getString("ifRange");
                    ifUnmod     = jsonreqHdrobject.getString("ifUnmod");
                    range       = jsonreqHdrobject.getString("range");
                    referer     = jsonreqHdrobject.getString("referer");
                    te          = jsonreqHdrobject.getString("te");
                    upgrade     = jsonreqHdrobject.getString("upgrade");
                    reqHdr_via  = jsonreqHdrobject.getString("via");
                    xFrwdFor    = jsonreqHdrobject.getString("xFrwdFor");
                    xReqWith    = jsonreqHdrobject.getString("xReqWith");
                }
            context.write(new Text("cloud_monitor"), new Text(type + format + version + id + start + cp + proto + protoVer + cliIP + reqPort + 
                    reqHost + reqMethod + reqPath + reqQuery + reqCT + reqLen + sslVer + status + redirURL + respCT + respLen + bytes + UA + fwdHost + accEnc   + accLang + auth + 
                    reqHdr_cacheCtl + reqHdr_conn + reqHdr_contMD5 + cookie + DNT + expect + ifMatch + ifMod + ifNone + ifRange + ifUnmod + range + referer + te +
                    upgrade + reqHdr_via + xFrwdFor + xReqWith ));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

I'm getting the following error message:

```
Error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.json.JSONException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByNameOrNull(Configuration.java:2138)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:2103)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2197)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.JobContextImpl.getMapperClass(JobContextImpl.java:196)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:745)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1693)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
```

Could anyone tell me if I am doing the JSON Parsing correctly, especially the JSON Arrays (message, reqHdr) part or how I can fix the bug ?

Comment: You have a `ClassNotFoundException` which means you have a dependency issue, where your code tries to run but can't find this class. You have a few options, ususally in hadoop you should create a fat jar which compiles all the dependencies into a single jar. You need something like this: https://www.mkyong.com/maven/create-a-fat-jar-file-maven-assembly-plugin/

Comment: @BinaryNerd I understand what you are saying but my project has only one Jar related to Json and I got it from: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json
These packages: org.json.JSONArray; org.json.JSONException; org.json.JSONObject; which are needed in the java program are imported without any version mismatch. I don't understand what is the need of creating a Fat jar when I have all the options available from the Jar I downloaded.

Comment: You have a run time error, the jar is available in your environment at compile time, thus your imports are working etc. When you try and run your code on your cluster, the question is how does your code have access to the JSON library you're using. If the jar isn't on the classpath you dont, thus you get a `ClassNotFoundException`. Compiling your dependencies into your final jar is a way to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

You have to download the org.json far file, and then add it to your project.

You can download the jar : [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json)

Comment: I guess ou wrote something like `import org.json.JSONObject;` in your code. But did you download the .jar, and add it to your project library ?

Comment: Yes I did. But as @Binarynerd on the other hand is saying, somehow the imports are not showing up on run time.